# Why does the service return me undefined when I request an item in Angular?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a service in Angular that returns an array of Any types

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import axios from "axios";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class BooksService {

  private books:any[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.books = this.getData()
  }

  getData()
  {
    axios.get(`https://localhost:3000/api/get`)
      .then(data => {
          return data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
          return error; 
      })
  }

  getBooks():any[]
  {
    return this.books;
  }

  getBook(idx:number):any
  {
    return this.books[idx]
  }
}
```

so when in my component I call the 'getBooks' function I get the following

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX412.png)

which works fine, but when I call the 'getBook()' function

```
console.log(this._booksService.getBook(1))
```

It returns 'undefined', does anyone know why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eY2z.png)

Comment: Why do you use axios instead of the Angular HttpClient service as used in the tutorials?

Comment: Hi ShamPooSham, because in the tutorial that I am taking they are using it, surely later they will show how to use httpClient

Comment: Follow the official Angular tutorials, they follow the best practices. There is **no** reason to use axios in Angular, it's just confusing to put it with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because the console.log function is not 'waiting' for the get request to get through. You should call the getBook function on the constructor, or anyways before calling console.log.

Comment: Thanks! You have given me an idea, I solved it by adding another variable of type any, then when calling the 'getBook' function I assign the item with the id passed as a parameter to this new variable and then return this one.